# How to make a recyclerview reload only if a button is pressed?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with some recyclerviews, but only one is important. I want this recyclerview not to upload the information automatically every time I get into the activity. I've called the method used to make it refresh pickEntidad, and i want to put this method inside an if, inside another method in which if this button is pressed, then the pickEntidad method will be called, otherwise nothing will happen and the information which the recyclerview will show will be the one which showed last time it refreshed.

I've tried to put the button called cambiarmenu inside an if, but these only accept a boolean. That's why I tried to make a variable value 1 if the button was pressed and then work with this variable in the if, but I didn't manage to do it correctly. (I called this method Clicado)

Here I leave you the code of the java.file.

```
public class Comida2 extends AppCompatActivity implements Adaptador2.OnRecipeListener {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView1;
    List<Entidad2> listItems;
    Adaptador2 adaptor;
    private Entidad2 entidad1,entidad2,entidad3;
    Button cambiarmenu;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comida);

        cambiarmenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_cambiarmenu);

        recyclerView1 = findViewById(R.id.lv_1);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        entidad1 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.calabacines_3, "Solomillo a la plancha", " 10 min.", 4, 20);
        entidad2 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.patatas_deluxe_especiadas_70523_300_150, "Entrecot", " 15 min.", 2, 50);
        entidad3 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.tomate, "Hamburguesa", " 2 min.", 5, 100);


        listItems.add(entidad1);
        listItems.add(entidad2);
        listItems.add(entidad3);

        adaptor = new Adaptador2(listItems, this);
        recyclerView1.setAdapter(adaptor);
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //Clicado();
    }

    @Override
    public void OnRecipe(int priority) {

        if (priority == 20) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Solomillo.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
        if (priority == 50) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Entrecot.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
        if (priority == 100) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Hamburguesa.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    }

    private void Clicado(){

        final boolean[] numerillo = new boolean[1];

        cambiarmenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                numerillo[0] = true;
            }
        });

            if (numerillo[0]) {
            pickEntidad();
        }
    }

    private void pickEntidad(){
        final int random = new Random().nextInt(101);

        int priority1 = entidad1.getPriority();
        int priority2 = entidad2.getPriority();
        int priority3 = entidad3.getPriority();


        listItems.clear();
        if(random < priority1){

            listItems.add(entidad1);

        }else if(random < priority2){

            listItems.add(entidad2);

        }else if (random <= priority3){

            listItems.add(entidad3);

        }
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

If anyone knows how to do it, please help me. And if you need more code, just ask.

Thanks.

Comment: Put your recyclerview and array adapter Initialization inside a method then call it if the button pressed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your idea correctly.

1. `recyclerview1` is displayed without any items at beginning.
2. When you click `R.id.lv_1` button in the layout, the recyclerview is filled with random items from entidad1~3 according to random priority by `pickEntidad()` method.
3. If you click this button again, the recyclerview is filled newly picked random items like above.
4. If you click one of the listed items, you go to another activity according to your pick.

As long as I understood, here's my solution.

```java
public class Comida2 extends AppCompatActivity implements Adaptador2.OnRecipeListener {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView1;
    List<Entidad2> listItems;
    Adaptador2 adaptor;
    private Entidad2 entidad1,entidad2,entidad3;
    Button cambiarmenu;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comida);

        cambiarmenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_cambiarmenu);

        recyclerView1 = findViewById(R.id.lv_1);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        entidad1 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.calabacines_3, "Solomillo a la plancha", " 10 min.", 4, 20);
        entidad2 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.patatas_deluxe_especiadas_70523_300_150, "Entrecot", " 15 min.", 2, 50);
        entidad3 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.tomate, "Hamburguesa", " 2 min.", 5, 100);


        /* Do not fill listItems here yet. */

        // listItems.add(entidad1);
        // listItems.add(entidad2);
        // listItems.add(entidad3);

        adaptor = new Adaptador2(listItems, this);
        recyclerView1.setAdapter(adaptor);
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();


        /* Clicado() method is useless in your mechanism */

        cambiarmenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            pickEntidad()
          }
      });
    }

    @Override
    public void OnRecipe(int priority) {

        if (priority == 20) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Solomillo.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
        if (priority == 50) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Entrecot.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
        if (priority == 100) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Hamburguesa.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    }

    private void pickEntidad(){
        final int random = new Random().nextInt(101);

        int priority1 = entidad1.getPriority();
        int priority2 = entidad2.getPriority();
        int priority3 = entidad3.getPriority();


        listItems.clear();
        if(random < priority1){

            listItems.add(entidad1);

        }else if(random < priority2){

            listItems.add(entidad2);

        }else if (random <= priority3){

            listItems.add(entidad3);

        }
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, what I want is that the items are shown all the time, but they only change (using pickEntidad method) when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your recyclerview has items by checking the item count in the adapter. If its null or empty add items to your recyclerview. Else, do nothing.
Your refresh button should have the pickEntidad() method to refresh;

```
//if list is empty add items
if (youradapter.itemCount == null || youradapter.itemCount == 0){
    pickEntidad ()
}

yourRefreshButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override public void onClick(View view) {
          pickEntidad()
      }
    });
```

Comment: I get the error message: cannot resolve itemCount, any idea of what it must be?

Comment: @cristianoronaldo can you show us the adapter class